# How to save expression in variable in PHP?

Tags: php

This might be bad question but I want to know if is it possible.

```
//here is my expression
$data = ($edit == 'allow') ? getData($id) : null;
```

Above expression interprets and saves in `$data` variable, is it possible to save it as a string and execute whenever need?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a [function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) instead

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Press, and hold down both the control- and _c_ key, do the same with the _v_ key where you need this statement again... or use _yy_ and _p_ in vim.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a closure that binds the `$edit` and `$id` variable to be used later:

```
$data = function() use ($id, $edit) {
    return ($edit == 'allow') ? getData($id) : null;
}

// later in your code
if ($data()) {
} else {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible:

```
$string = '$data = ($edit == \'allow\') ? getData($id) : null;';
```

To run the expression, just evaluate it.

```
eval($string);
```

Now you can use the `$data` variable as you need it.

Comment: It's a terrible idea to introduce `eval` without mentioning its evilness.

Comment: There is nothing "evil" about `eval`. The evilness comes in it's use. In this case, the developer has absolute control over the string being evaluated, and there is no danger at all.

Comment: @GarethCornish: _"When all you have is the `eval` hammer, everything looks like your thumb."_ - There is no good case to be made for eval here: It's slower, less safe (no matter what you say) and utter overkill. A function, closure or just _writing the ternary a second time_ are all better alternatives

Comment: This is specifically what the thread asks for, however there is inherent danger if you for example take input from a user that this string pulls data from. There are probably better ways to accomplish what you would like, for example, a function.

Answer (score 0):

You use the [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) construct for that purpose:

```
$expression = "(\$edit == \'allow\') ? getData(\$id) : null;";
eval($expression);
```

but this is dangerous as it can execute potentially malicious code. Use it carefully.